# How to get data from json file using angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How to get json data from json file and how to display using only angular 2.I did but not working. Can you find where i did mistake

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-fkngjs?file=app/app.component.html

```
this.http.request('http://localhost:4200/app/jsondata/details.json?home=place&owner=person&minval=min&maxval=max').
subscribe((res) => {
let alldetails = JSON.stringify(res); 
});
```

Comment: using http://localhost:4200 on stackblitz wont work

Comment: is the file available locally? what's the query string for? is there somewhere this data is available online?

Comment: @gayathri n check my answer, you missed an import

Comment: @gayathri, your .json file must be in assests folder and make que request about this.http.get('assets/details.json').subscribe(res=>this.alldetails=res). See that using httpClient you need'nt use JSON.stringfy. The .json must be in folder assest (or in a server) because when angular-cli build the projects you only get index.html, a few "bundels files" (.js and css) and folder assest. There're not capacity to read "localhost:4200/app/jsondata"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import `HttpClientModule` in your app.module.ts like below

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

You need to use it in your `@NgModule` like below -

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ExampleComponent,HeaderComponent,FooterComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Here is the complete code for app.module.ts -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';



@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ExampleComponent,HeaderComponent,FooterComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But however if you are using Angular 2 only then you need to import `HttpModule` from '@angular/http' instead of `HttpClientModule` in your app.module.ts.Also you need to use `Http` from '@angular/http' instead of `HttpClient` in your app.component.ts

Here is a working demo - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-gunqm4

Comment: @gayathrin which functionality is not working? are you getting any error?it works fine for me .

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-cnyhaz?file=app/app.component.ts        Not working..I am not able to get json values

Comment: I am waiting for your answer

Comment: @gayathrin i can see the dropdowns in the example . which json data are you referring to? are you showing the data in UI.

Comment: @gayathrin you need to remove the localhost api path and just use "jsondata/details.json" in your api call . Before that you need add the "jsondata" folder to your angular-cli.json file under "assets" inside "app"